# MSSQL CLR Trigger problems

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

So normally I don't get stuck on SQL and I don't give up with ample amounts of my own research. but I have exhausted all thoughts I can and all possibilities that I can think of.

Situation: programmer built a CLR trigger for me. ( I am SQL Guy, not C# guy). This trigger uses filesystem so a couple things needed to be altered since we didn't bother signing it for now.

So Ran the following on the DB before install

```
ALTER DATABASE [DBName] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
USE [DBName]
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa'
GO
```

After this. I executed a UI that connects to the Database and installs the trigger. This was working no problem until recently. Then After a couple uninstalls and reinstalls it no longer works.

Now the current code works on his machine in his environment. Install / UnInstall. And if I Turn trustworthy back to off

```
ALTER DATABASE [DBName] SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF;
```

It tries to load the assembly and fails. Turn it back on. It supposedly loads the assembly. But the trigger doesn't do anything. For reference. We are both using the same database same user ids (for now sa for testing).

So I guess my question. How do I know it's truely loading the assembly? Why isn't the assembly throwing errors or doing standard things it's supposed to do like creating log files.

For example one of this first tasks to do is to create a log file. It reads data from an XML file that is stored on the server. I put in the log file location abc. So it should error and be like I can't find this location or something. But nothing. So to me, it seems like the assembly is not being loaded at all. Any way to verify the assembly is truly being loaded and executed?

Anything anyone can tell me how to see any errors that might not be showing in output or debug?

Comment: Just as a comment. Uninstall and install still works from UI. It is installed into sql assembly folder and I can see the trigger on the DB

Comment: You can *[edit]* your question to add more information. You should never need to comment in direct reply to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

So This is completely an error in the C# code. My programmer finally found the error. Nothing was wrong with the SQL Side. I was going Mad. Thanks for anyone who read this. I apologize.

He was reading certain directory locations from wrong locations. and if if directories did not exist he was exiting code. he feels bad I feel relieved. Thanks sorry for bothering.